# Navigation with Button to open Page (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, navigation

I want to make a Navigation (Home,Media,Contact...) and i want it like this that 
if you press Home it opens the Home(Page) in a Slide down so it doesnt use any href in the Navigation.

Again and easy explained:
I have a navigation with Buttons(Image) i want to click a Button to open the other Image in a slide down.

And yes im new to all of this and i want to learn but googled and didnt find anything that helped me.

Thats what I tried but it didnt work(Nothing Happens):

**CSS:**

```
.Home { 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-image: url("../images/Home.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 179px;
    left: 155px;
    z-index:3
    }
.Home:hover {
    background-image: url("../images/Homeh.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 178px;
    left: 155px;
    z-index:2
    }
.panel {
    background-image: url("../images/Panel.png");
    position: absolute;
    width: 1699px;
    height: 843px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 120px;
    z-index:1
    }
```

**Html:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Home").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a><span class="Home"></span></a>
<a><span class="panel"></span></a>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery's built in function [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), which will change an element's CSS on the fly. You can control the speed at which they change and also the order in which you want your animations to take place.

To get the panel to slide down from the top, you must first create the panel with it's top position equal to negative of whatever height the panel is. Then use **animate()** to move it down/up.

So in your code, change:

```
.panel {
    top: 200px;
}
```

To this:

```
.panel {
    top: -843px; /* Height of panel */
}
```

And then with Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function dropDown() {
        $('.home').one('click', function(){
            $('.panel').animate({
                top: "+=900"
            }, 400, function() {
                $('.home').one('click', function(){
                    $('.panel').animate({
                        top: '-=900'
                    }, 400, function() {
                        dropDown();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })();
  
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7tobeyz/5/) with image backgrounds

**Update**

You can also make the div drop down from a specific part of the document by using jQuery's [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function. It takes the provided selector and calculates it's distance from the document's edge in pixels. In this case you would set your drop-down div's top position equal to the home button's offset (while still subtracting it's own height).

Example:

```
// Height of drop-down element
var height = $('.panel').height();

// Position drop-down element right above target button
var yPosition = $('.home').offset().top - height;
$('.panel').css('top', yPosition+'px');

(function dropDown() {

    $('.home').one('click', function(){
        $('.panel').css({
            'display': 'block',
            'opacity': 0
        });      
    
        $('.panel').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: "+=250"
        }, 400, function() {
            $('.home').one('click', function(){
            $('.panel').animate({
                opacity: 0,
                top: '-=250'
                }, 400, function() {
                    dropDown();
                });
            });
        }); 
    });
        
})();
```

Full demo - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7tobeyz/12/)

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[css](/questions/tagged/css)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

Comment: So i can use this also for picture based buttons/boxes?

Comment: Another one how can i let it slide out from the same height as the button becouse my navigation is like 200px from the top and it doesnt look good if it comes out from the top of the screen.

Comment: I updated my answer again and also provided a full example

Comment: Thanks that helpd me but it doesnt appear it fades in i want it to do not fade in i want it to slide down under the navigation.

Comment: Not a problem. Take a look at the fiddle again and let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it to work. If my examples helped, please be sure to accept, thanks.